# What is the difference between use{} and apply{} in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
cursor?.apply{
    this.moveToFirst() 
}

cursor?.use{
    it.moveToFirst() 
}
```

The only difference I see is between `it` and `this`, that is the same instance. But, is there any other difference?

Answer (score 3):

`use()` can only be called with a `Closeable` receiver. After the block is executed, the `Closeable` resource is closed, which saves boilerplate.

You can see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html for more information on all the scope functions. `use()` is essentially the same as `let()`, except with the addtional auto-closing feature.

Comment: Maybe you can add that `apply` returns the context object and you can add the doc links for [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) and [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html).